Do you have an idiom roughly like "they put him on to the cloud" to mean they praise him too much?
In Vietnamese, we say "they put him on to the cloud after he scored a goal helping the team to the final" (literally translated from Vietnamese) to mean they praise him too much after he scored a goal which helps the team to go to the final match.
Do you have idioms roughly like that in English?

We can praise someone to the heavens, but that doesn’t mean the same thing. It means, more or less, heap praises on someone. And it doesn’t carry the connotation of excess. In fact, it’s usually used in contexts where all of the praise is suitable.

"praise him too much" in the sense that the goal wasn't a wonderful display of skill, like a carom off his hip that just happened to find the goal?

"Put him on a pedestal" is the closest, and very close to an exact match. If you changed your translation of the Vietnamese to "put him on A cloud" I think you would be understood, although it is definitely not idiomatic. I'm sure there are other options which others will suggest.

English has idioms that convey similar meanings. Here are a few examples:
Ref. Collins dictionary

1."Put on a pedestal":.
in American English.
or set on a pedestal.
to regard with great or excessive admiration; idolize idealizing them.
2."Hail as a hero":.
If a person, event, or achievement is hailed as important or successful, they are praised publicly remarkable achievement.
3."Make a fuss over someone":.
(idiom)  in the sense of spoil.
My nephews made a big fuss of me.
Synonyms.
spoil, indulge, pamper, cosset, coddle, mollycoddle, overindulge

